# How can I put number or A-F or space immediatly after %d in output file name of Ghostscript?

Tags: windows, printf, ghostscript

I'm using Windows 10 and Ghostscript 10.02.1 (2023-11-01) installed via Scoop.

## What doesn't work

If `%d` is followed by hex number or space or [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus), it doesn't work:

```
# PowerShell 7
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%d0.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
# or
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%dF.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
# or
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%d q.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
# or
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%d-.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
```

(Or in CMD: `gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%dF.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "test file.pdf"`)

The error message:

> Page 1
> GPL Ghostscript 10.02.1: **** Could not open the file '1-.jpeg'.
> **** Error: Page drawing error occurred.
> Could not draw this page at all, page will be missing in the output.

(Notice that the reported string is '1-.jpeg', which is exactly what I naively expect to get from "%d-.jpeg".)

## What works

But if the very next symbol is not hexadecimal & not space & not hyphen-minus, it works:

```
# PowerShell 7
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%dG.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
# or
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%dZ.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
# or
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%d! 42 F0 0F.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
# or
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%d~.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 'test file.pdf'
```

(Or in CMD: `gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o "%dg.jpeg" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "test file.pdf"`)

## A possible lead

> The format specifier is of a form similar to the C printf format.
> [...]
> For more information, please refer to documentation on the C printf format specifications.
>
> [Using Ghostscript — Ghostscript 10.03.0 documentation](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#one-page-per-file)

I didn't figure out anything of value by using a search engine for this.

## “Conclusion”

The name I want is `%d foo.jpeg`. Of course, I can simply compromise with `%dp foo.jpeg` instead. But I'm curious about reasons of and workaround for this quirky syntax issue.

Comment: The documentation tells you why it doesn't work. The '%d' is a printf style format specifier it means 'an integer goes here'.. There are numerous format specifiers for printf, you have to avoid using anything that looks like (or is) a format specifier if you want to use %d. Here's a simple tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm Since you are using a single page there's no reason to use %d to emit the page number. If you actually want to use a '%' character then you need to double the % characters, so "%%d.jpeg" will result in the filename '%d.jpeg'.

Comment: @KenS I does work in [an online C playground.](https://onlinegdb.com/Ile0D-0X6)
Furthermore, the resultant strings reported in the error messages seem completely fine. I.e. the end string itself looks valid but still rejected for some reason.

Comment: It's not real printf, it's just **like** printf. Your C test isn't the same I'm afraid.